# MS gate in qiskit

Tags: qiskit

Does anyone know how to use the Mølmer–Sørensen (MS) gate in qiskit? The documentation is highly unintuitive and does not provide examples.

If one has to use the [generalized version](https://docs.quantum.ibm.com/api/qiskit/qiskit.circuit.library.GMS#gms),
what is actually theta? How do I select which qubit will get entangled with such matrix? If I build my circuit with `circuit = QuantumCircuit(qreg_q, creg_c)`, how to call the "library" in order to get the gms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the gate that you're looking for is the qiskit `RXXGate` gate. Its understandable to be unsure as I've heard both terms used referring to the same gate.

According to [the docs](https://docs.quantum.ibm.com/api/qiskit/qiskit.circuit.library.RXXGate) the unitary for the `RXXGate` is

$$
R_{XX}(\theta) = \exp\big(-i \frac{\theta}{2} X \otimes X\big)\,.
$$

```python
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
from qiskit.circuit.library import RXXGate

qc = QuantumCircuit(2)
qc.append(RXXGate(theta=0.27), [0, 1])
```

Comment: Haha yes.. how dumb of me, this is easier and already on board to implement.

Comment: Glad to have helped. The confusion is understandable.

Comment: Just to note for GMS usage, it's a circuit in the circuit library. You would include it, like any of the other library circuits, into your own circuit by say, using qc.compose() on your circuit to include it.